¿Por qué me da Promise{<pendig>}?
Por alguna razón me devuelve Promise{<pending>}
export default async function get(url) {
  const data = await axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      return res.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  return data
}


Una función async siempre devuelve una promesa

"Por alguna razón", estas usando async/await con then/catch, lo que ves es una promesa pendiente, al imprimirlo en consola intentas ver algo que todavía no se resuelve, esto por el await.
La forma fácil de resolverlo es:
export default async function get(url) {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return null;
  }
}

